# Why vue.js component is not set the Data from method

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I successfully get data from an Axios request. then assign to data users but it show error.
Type Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'users').

here is my code.

```
     <template>
        <div class="p-5">
    
            <h1 class="text-2xl mb-4">Certifly Live Video Chat </h1>
            <div id ="users">
            </div>
            <div id="myid" class="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-4 bg-black/]">
                <button class="btn btn-info" style="margin-right:5px" v-for="user in users" @click="getAccessToken(user.appt_room_name)" > 
                    {{user.appt_admin_name}} {{user.appt_date_time}}
                </button>
    
                <br><br>
                <div id="video-chat-window">
                </div> 
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </template>
<script>
         export default {
                name: 'video-chat',        
                data() {
                    return {
                        users:[]
                    };
                },         
                methods : {
                     userRequests: function(){
                        axios.post(`/api/user_requests`)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response.data)
                            this.users = response.data.data;  
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }) 
                    }, 
        
        
                     
                },
                mounted : function () { 
                    this.userRequests();
                }
            }
</script>
```

console data
[
{
"id": 1,
"appt_date_time": "03:00 - 03:15",
"appt_admin_id": 15,
"appt_admin_name": "Osana Shiraz",
"appt_usr_id": 280965,
"appt_usr_name": "Hamza Shiraz",
"appt_room_name": "RMX:280965",
"created_at": "2021-12-21 14:50:59",
"updated_at": "2021-12-21 14:50:59"
},
{
"id": 3,
"appt_date_time": "04:30 - 04:45",
"appt_admin_id": 15,
"appt_admin_name": "Osana Shiraz",
"appt_usr_id": 280965,
"appt_usr_name": "awais",
"appt_room_name": "RMX:280965",
"created_at": "2021-12-21 17:04:09",
"updated_at": "2021-12-21 17:04:09"
},
{
"id": 4,
"appt_date_time": "05:15 - 05:30",
"appt_admin_id": 15,
"appt_admin_name": "Osana Shiraz",
"appt_usr_id": 280965,
"appt_usr_name": "awais",
"appt_room_name": "RMX:280965",
"created_at": "2021-12-21 17:06:50",
"updated_at": "2021-12-21 17:06:50"
}
];

Comment: when I assign response data to "this.users" . it give error Type Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'users').

Comment: can you post your template too?

Comment: also the 'console.log(response.data) output

Comment: simply i want to assign the userRequset to users array following
data() {
        return {
                users:[]
                    };
      }

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to `this` in your `.then` callback. So you're trying to assign something to `users` on undefined.
[This article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/access-%22this%22-in-a-promise%27s-catch-block) explains the reason why.
Try changing your promise callback to use an arrow function, such as:

```
userRequests: function() {
  axios.post('/api/user_requests')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
        this.users = response.data.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: thank you @Will F it work for me using arrow function

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
export default {
  name: "videoChat",
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async userRequests() {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/user_requests`);
        this.users = data;
      } catch (error) {
          console.log('error', error)
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.userRequests();
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign to `users[]` just `response.data` and not `response.data.data` . Here you have a functional example:
https://codepen.io/jssDev-/pen/zYEExbq

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `arrow` function, you can also save `this` reference and use it later in the function. Make sure to do this before the `axios` call.

```
userRequests: function() {
  let vm = this
  axios.post(`/api/user_requests`).then(function (response) {
    vm.users = response.data.data
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }) 
},
```